# Why isn't my 'join' action working, it says the action 'show' can't be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my UserController I have:

```
def join
end
```

I have a join.html.erb in my /views/user/ folder.

My routes has a :

```
resources :user
```

When I go to:

http://localhost:3000/user/join

I get:

The action 'show' could not be found for UserController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using resources, but have a non-REST action, so you need to add the join action to the route with the appropriate HTTP verb:

```
map.resources :users, :member => { :join => :get }
```

Answer (score 5):

**Re: why isn't the join action found?**

To answer your specific question, what's happening is that you want to have an action "join" for your User model.

Your problem is that you haven't defined a route matching the url http://localhost:3000/user/join

The line `resources :user` in your routes file only defines routes for the seven standard rest verbs/actions:

index, new, create, show, edit, update, destroy

See: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Resources/resources

Added: to fix, you'll need to add an explicit or generic route. [Routing docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Added: *Re: why am I seeing the error message re show?* To be ultra-precise, the route selector "GET /usr/:id" (created by your resource call) is being used to select the SHOW action for the User resource. The :id value is being set to "join". Since you don't have a Show method defined in your controller, that's the error that you're seeing.

Comment: The generic route Larry mentions would look like this: `resources :user do
  member do
    get 'join'
  end
end`

Answer (score 0):

Place:

```
def show
end
```

in your UserController.

To be certain:

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
def join
end
```

**app/views/users/join.html.erb**

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :users
```

Comment: but /user/join I want to use the 'join' action in the usercontroller, not the 'show' action.

Comment: I'm just suggesting that you fix the error you're getting first. Maybe your answer will be more visible once you do.

Comment: Sorry if my answer is lacking. I'm still new to RoR. I'm just offering what little I know to try and help out. Hope you find your answer!